My Goal is to replace "Start > Run > "notepad" with launching VSCode instead of notepad. I want the same behaviour for Powershell > "notepad FILE1"
This is a tricky question.
Notepad3.exe comes with a commandline option called /z
Notepad++.exe comes with a commandline option called -notepadStyleCmdline -z
VSCode does not come with this option.
Thus when I use this registry hack it always launches Code.exe, but then immediately attempts to open "notepad.exe" binary inside vscode. What can I do to fix this behaviour? Or should we put a feature request in VSCode's github for a "-notepadStyleCmdline" like command line option? I think this would be immensely useful.
Here is what I have so far, using a portable vscode unzipped file to temp:
FILE: set-notepad-to-vscode.bat
@ECHO OFF & CLS & ECHO.
@REM THIS SCRIPT Replace Notepad on Windows 11 with VSCode

NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO You must right-click and select &  ECHO "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR"  to run this batch. Exiting... & ECHO. &  Timeout /t 10 & EXIT /B)
SETLOCAL
::
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\temp\VSCode-Notepad\Code.exe\" -n " /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe\0" /v "FilterFullPath" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\temp\VSCode-Notepad\Code.exe" /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe\1" /v "FilterFullPath" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\temp\VSCode-Notepad\Code.exe" /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe\2" /v "FilterFullPath" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\temp\VSCode-Notepad\Code.exe" /f

ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF

FILE: reset-notepad-to-notepad-original.bat
@ECHO OFF & CLS & ECHO.
@REM The following code Reverses the change

NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO You must right-click and select &  ECHO "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR"  to run this batch. Exiting... & ECHO. &  Timeout /t 10 & EXIT /B)
SETLOCAL
reg delete "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe" /v "Debugger" /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe\0" /v "FilterFullPath" /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad.exe" /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe\1" /v "FilterFullPath" /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad.exe" /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe\2" /v "FilterFullPath" /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad.exe" /f
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF

Do you guys have any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I know it is a finicky request, but I appreciate help!
Thanks!!


Your question is very unclear. What do the -z arguments do? When you use WHAT registry hack? We can't advise regarding whether or not you ought to submit a feature change request for VSCode. While I'm glad you've solved your problem, because it is not clear precisely what you are trying to accomplish to begin with, we do not know the problem you are having and therefore do not understand the context within which that answer lives, making it less than useful for the rest of the community or to this site. Please EDIT your question to make it more clear and complete.

I figured it out. I had to write a wrapper, and replace the Windows Notepad.exe with my powershell script that launches vscode.
Details:

First make this powershell script vscode-wrapper.ps1

param([string]$file)

# Path to VS Code executable
$vscodePath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
$vscodePath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\Code - Insiders.exe" #**You can use either, im leaving code as my main with all my normal configs, but insiders will be used as my minimal "notepad.exe replacement"**

# Check if VS Code is installed
if (Test-Path $vscodePath) {
    # Launch VS Code with the file
    if ($file) {
        Start-Process $vscodePath -ArgumentList "`"$file`""
    } else {
        Start-Process $vscodePath
    }
} else {
    # Fallback to Notepad if VS Code is not installed
    if ($file) {
        Start-Process "notepad.exe" -ArgumentList "`"$file`""
    } else {
        Start-Process "notepad.exe"
    }
}


Compile it to a new "notepad.exe" file which launches the above script:

ps2exe -NoConsole .\vscode-wrapper.ps1 .\Notepad.exe


Psexec (psexec -s) a TrustedInstaller privelaged powershell window, and then paste this into it (adjust the FILL ME IN folder appropriately):


cd "WHERE YOUR NEW EXE FILE IS <-- FILL ME IN"

cp "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.orig.exe" -verbose

cp ".\Notepad.exe" "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" -verbose



Thats it! Now you can...

start > run > notepad <--- and it will launch code insiders!

powershell > "notepad FILE1" <-- and it will do the same


finally, configure your vscode insiders to have these unique settings to behave more like a minimal notepad:

- open up vscode insiders and add the CTRL+, configs:

Search for "startup" then:
    Workbench: Startup Editor > "newUntitledFile"
    Terminal › Integrated: Hide On Startup > always
    PowerShell › Integrated Console: > UNCHECK SHOW ON STARTUP for SPEED
Search for "new window" then:
    Window: Open Files In New Window > ON
    Window: Open Folders In New Window > ON
Search for "trust"
    Workbench › Trusted Domains: prompt in trusted > uncheck
Trust: Banner > never
Trust: Enabled > UNCHECKED

...launch it once, if it says "pick a language or something", or click this to disable the message, do so.


Hint: You can make notepad launch gvim or neovide instead if you change the powershell path and recompile appropriately too
